In Java, is it possible to concatenate the contents of two PDF files in order to concatenate the visible contents of the files?
I have a back-end Java application that grabs the contents of PDF files from a blob in the database, and puts them into a byte[] array to be able to download.
My end goal - if possible - is to append the contents of one file to another file such that a single download will display it as a single PDF file that contains the contents of both files.
For example, if one PDF file is a one-page file that says 'PDF File 1 Contents', and another PDF file is a one-page file that says 'PDF File 2 Contents' - I would like to combine the contents to a two-page PDF file that has 'PDF File 1 Contents' on the first page and 'PDF File 2 Contents' on the second page.
I though maybe I could do this by concatenating the byte[] arrays of the two files like so:
public void getDocument(HttpServletResponse response) {
    
    byte[] docContent1 = documentDao.getDocument(blah, blah, blah);
    byte[] docContent2 = documentDao.getDocument(blah, blah, blah);

    byte[] concatenatedFile = new byte[docContent1.length + docContent2.length];

    System.arraycopy(docContent1, 0, concatenatedFile, 0, docContent1.length);

    System.arraycopy(docContent2, 0, concatenatedFile, docContent1.length, sfiDocContent2.length);

    HttpServletResponse response = new HttpServletResponse();
    response.setContentType(blah);
    response.getOutputStream().write(concatenatedFile);
}

However, all that is displayed after the download is the contents of docContent2.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

In a nutshell: no, you cannot simply concatenate two PDFs to merge them. Instead you need to parse the contents of the source files and rearrange them according to the PDF spec. Or take existing PDF libraries and let them do the job.

You'll need a library for this - I would recommend PdfBox.  Another possibility which I've had some good results with is iText. There are answers using both those libraries in the question that another user mentioned in their comment.
